# Java: Embed a HTML or PDF into a JFrame

Tags: java, html, pdf, jframe, jeditorpane

I am open to alternative solutions, so here is my problem.

I have 111 PDFs that contain information on various degree programs. I can convert them to HTML using freeware.

The problem with the HTML is that it contains CSS, JEditorPane doesn't display the webpage, and the PDF libraries are slow and bulky.

I want to have a JCombobox where users can select a page to view, and have it appear below the box.

Any ideas on the best method?

Comment: Are you trying to display html in JEditorPane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) API for PDF and [DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/) for HTML/webPage.

Comment: DJ Project from what I remember only works on 32bit win, unless i am mistaken.

I would prefer something more multi-platform

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries that convert PDF to HTML can also convert PDF to image.

If you can convert to SVG and display it using one of the SVG libraries (E.g. [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)), that would be one way you could display it without losing any functionality like zoom in/out.

Otherwise you can convert PDF to high-res JPG/PNG and display it in your app.